# md5-encrypted string returns different from database than it is inserted

Tags: c#, asp.net

So, I try to check if passwords match.

This is the encryption I use, once when the data is inserted in the database, once to check if the inserted password on the login field matches the one from the database:

```
 byte[] pass = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
 MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
 string newPass = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(md5.ComputeHash(pass));
```

But every time I try to login (with correct details), it does not work. In the debugger, this is the string that comes from the database:

```
?]??$PL??f??6?
```

And the one encrypted from the login field:

```
�]��$PL��fඇ�6�
```

I suppose it's an encoding problem, but can't seem to figure it out myself.

Comment: Looks like an *encoding* problem and your database is not storing the data correctly.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I meant, not encryption. Edited.

Comment: MD5 is not ecryption it a hashing algorithm. If the two values do not match this might be a encoding problem. Make you are using the same encoding in both cases.  If this is a password then you should be aware MD5 hashing is trivial process to brute force.  There are rainbow tables for every possible md5 value.  Your current method does not even use a salt which makes accessing any account trivial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line is inappropriate:

```
string newPass = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(md5.ComputeHash(pass));
```

`ComputeHash` returns arbitrary binary data. Either you should keep it as binary data, or if you *do* need to convert it to text, use Base64 to convert it in a way which will allow you to get back the original data later:

```
string base64Hash = Convert.ToBase64String(md5.ComputeHash(pass));
```

You should be fine to store that as a normal string - it'll just be ASCII.

(I wouldn't personally use MD5 to hash passwords, but that's a different conversation.)

Answer (score 3):

The [`ComputeHash`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s02tk69a.aspx) method returns an array of bytes, *not* an array of encoded characters.

The [`GetString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc.aspx) method expects an array of encoded characters as input, *not* an array of arbitrary bytes.

If `newPass` is meant to be a string then you need to convert the array of arbitrary bytes to a format that can properly represent an array of arbitrary bytes as a string. For example, Base-64 encoding:

```
string newPass - Convert.ToBase64String(md5.ComputeHash(pass));
```

Answer (score 0):

A guess, but is the database field a CHAR or VARCHAR instead of an NCHAR or NVARCHAR? The 'N' variants are Unicode (and how you encoded the btyes), like .Net strings.

Comment: Of course, if he's going to keep it as binary he would want to use a database field of type `binary` or `varbinary`.

Comment: @Brian: In his example, he is converting it to a UTF8 encoded string. But yes, it would make sense to not convert it in the first place, and story it directly as binary. Either way works.

Comment: No, switching the database to store unicode wouldn't actually help.  The data has already been corrupted by `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(` before it even gets to the database.  Even if he stores his UTF8 string in the database perfectly, the string itself doesn't actually represent his original binary data.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, the readable characters are the same in both cases (you can clearly see the $PL stick out in the middle). Since this is the result of an md5 hash, you can assume the input data is equal.

The first line looks like it was converted to ASCII rather than to UTF8, where all non-ASCII characters are changed to a `?`.

If I were you I wouldn't try to convert binary data (the md5 output) to a string directly, but use a hexadecimal representation instead, something like:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
foreach (byte b in md5hash) 
{
    result.Append(b.ToString("X2"));
}
```